# T-SQL : Using Stuff statement with Dates results in Conversion error

Tags: date

I'm slowly learning how to use a stuff statement, so far its been a minor success.

I use stuff to populate one column in one line with all values matching.

eg.

```
 SELECT table1.ID, STUFF((SELECT ',' + table2.Value
            FROM Table1 WITH (NOLOCK)
            WHERE Table1.id = table2.id 
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, NULL) AS [concat_values]
from table1, table2
where table1.id = table2.id
and table1.status = 'Open'
```

The above works great...however I hit a brick wall when I use it with a date.

Eg.

```
 SELECT table1.ID, STUFF((SELECT ',' + table2.Date
            FROM Table1 WITH (NOLOCK)
            WHERE Table1.id = table2.id 
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, NULL) AS [concat_dates]
from table1, table2
where table1.id = table2.id
and table1.status = 'Open'
```

I get an "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value." error, one the first line.

The dates in the database is supposed to be YYYY/MM/DD but oftens shows as YYYY/MM/DD 00:00:00.000, would this have an impact?

Does anyone know why this is happening and what I am doing wrong?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the date to varchar inside your call to `STUFF`:

```
 SELECT
    t1.ID,
    STUFF((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(varchar, table2.Date, 120)
           FROM Table1 WITH (NOLOCK)
           WHERE Table1.id = t2.id 
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, NULL) AS [concat_dates]
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.status = 'Open'
```

The issue is that when you say `',' + table2.Date` you are telling SQL Server to concatenate `t2.Date` with another string.  If my solution does not work, then perhaps your date information has a problem.